# order price format in custom module

Tags: magento-1.8, price, grid, sales-order, format

I am bit confused magento price data formating is done, I am working on custome module whete I need to display order amount in grid, I done it, its working fine but I am getting 4 places of decimal points for example 14.0000, I need it display like 14.00 only,

my grid add column function that print order amount is as below.

```
$this->addColumn('order_amount', array(
          'header'    => Mage::helper('manoreport')->__('Order Amount'),
          'width'     => '100px',
          'type'=>'price',
          'index'     => 'subtotal_invoiced',
        ));
```

but it still looks like this only

[image]

Any Suggestions.?
Thanks in Advance:)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to specify a currency.

```
$this->addColumn('order_amount', array(
      'header'    => Mage::helper('manoreport')->__('Order Amount'),
      'width'     => '100px',
      'type'      => 'price',
      'index'     => 'subtotal_invoiced',
      'currency_code' => 'CURRENCY CODE HERE' 
    ));
```

If the currency may be different from order to order (most probably is) you can make the column be of type `currency` instead of `price`.

```
$this->addColumn('order_amount', array(
      'header'    => Mage::helper('manoreport')->__('Order Amount'),
      'width'     => '100px',
      'type'      => 'currency',
      'index'     => 'subtotal_invoiced',
      'currency'  => 'order_currency_code'//this will take the currency from the order - this represents the column that holds the currency code
    ));
```

Comment: When i tried to use 'order_currency_code', Magento complained "Currency 'order_currency_code' does not exist". Instead i had to create a renderer extending the Currency renderer, get the currency code from the order passed into the renderer function and set that on the column object, then return the parent::renderer

Comment: How to achieve this in magento 2 custom grid?